# VS 2010: LNK2019 error for Win7 API

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I'm trying to use a Win7 API. I copy/pasted a code sample, and it won't compile because of `LNK2019` errors. However, if I go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows", I see that I have the necessary `.lib` files.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that the files are on my machine, but VS isn't recognizing them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the .LIB is included in the SDK path you'll need to explicitly specify the ones to be linked inside the project compilation options.  Are all of the .LIB files you require explicitly specified in the project compilation options?